# Is it possible in TeXShop to create a new file from the selected text?

Tags: mac, texshop

How can I select text within a tex file in TeXShop on Mac and outsource it into another file tex file?

Suppose I have a text in a file
`Dolorem ipsum color sit amet.`
I would like to select it and convert it into a new file with few clicks or pressing few keys, with \input or \include command in the original file
`\input{ipsum}`

This was a feature in Texniccenter which I used a lot on Windows, but cannot find it in TeXShop on MacOS.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. I may have misunderstood your question. You can't create a new `.tex` file from selected text directly in TeXShop; if that's what you want to do then my answer doesn't solve that problem, but it doe show you how to create a macro from selected text. It may be possible to make an Applescript to do what you want, however.

Comment: Select the text and Copy it (Cmd-C). Open a new document and Paste it (Cmd-V). Doesn’t that work?

Comment: @AlanMunn It was indeed the purpose to create a new .tex file and leave \input{path-to-the-tex-file} in the original tex file.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Copy-paste works but this is about efficiency. Ideally, a single (Cmd-?) would replace (Cmd-X), (Cmd-N), (Cmd-V) and typing file name twice during saving and in \input.